# Facebook Login for the iOS app occurring outside of the appliaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Facebook` login for my `iOS` app .For the first time the user needs to login via `Facebook`and When a login is asked the app is redirecting to Safari browser or it will redirect to the `Facebook` app if the Facebook app is installed on your device.

But now we require the `Facebook` login to take place within our app.

Could this be possible.Please help to find this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please put this line :

```
loginButton.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

Comment: What i'm asking is that the app login takes place by redirecting to the browser or the Facebook App . How can we ask for FB login within the our app itself?..

Comment: please check my edited answer  user `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb` it will open popups

Answer (score 0):

use FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount as loginBehavior. App will use facebook account configured on iphone settings

Comment: Ya this could also be used .. but now i'm using the one said above.